# "How To" for adding a plugin to Nagios

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu, nagios

Is there a "how to" for adding and configuring a plugin to Nagios? (for Ubuntu 14.04 specifically, but any Linux OS would be helpful.)

I've been able to cobble this much so far:

1. Place the script in /usr/local/nagios/libexec/. (In my case there was already a script I wanted to use: "check_file_age".)
2. Edit /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg to add the plugin.

```
define command{  
    command_name check_file_age  
    command_line $USER1$/check_file_age -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -W $ARG3$ -C $ARG4$ -f $ARG5$ 
}
```

3. Define the plugin in /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/localhost.cfg.

```
define service{
    use             generic-service     ; Name of service template to use
    host_name           localhost
    service_description     File Age
    check_command           check_file_age
    notifications_enabled       1
}
```

Now I can see the plugin under "Configuration -> Object Type: Command" and I can see it listed in "Configuration -> Object Type: Services".

The plugin runs successfully from the command line:

```
user@host:/usr/local/nagios/libexec$ perl ./check_file_age -w 3600 -c 5400 -W -1 -C -1 -f somefile.txt 
FILE_AGE OK: somefile.txt is 2932 seconds old and 59 bytes | age=2932s;3600;5400 size=59B;-1;-1;0
```

Then at this point I'm stumped. I can see this error in Services:

```
File Age
CRITICAL    
09-09-2015 14:24:21 
0d 0h 32m 1s    
3/3 
(No output on stdout) stderr: Can't locate utils.pm in @INC (you may need to install the utils module) (@INC contains: . /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_file_age line 30. 
HTTP
Notifications for this service have been disabled
OK  09-09-2015 14:30:53 0d 4h 3m 30s    1/4
```

How do I specify what arguments to pass? How do I correct the error? What's next? (Is there a single location that describes how to add a plugin that escaped my Google-fu?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Issue 1:

The `check_file_age` plugin is a perl script that requires another perl module called `utils.pm`.  Are they both in the same folder?  If not, find the location of `utils.pm`:

```
find / -name "utils.pm" -type f
```

You will need to add the path of the folder containing `utils.pm` to your `$PERL5LIB` environment variable for your nagios user or whatever user is running the nagios daemon service.

Take the path to the folder of utils.pm and add it to a shell script that we'll place in the `/etc/profile.d/` folder.  For example, if the results of your find command were `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/utils.pm` then execute something like this:

```
echo "export PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:/usr/local/nagios/libexec" >> /etc/profile.d/nagiosplugins.sh
chmod a+x /etc/profile.d/nagiosplugins.sh
source /etc/profile
```

With any luck, that should take care of the `Can't locate utils.pm in @INC` error.

## Issue 2:

You need to fix your service definition to pass in the expected arguments to `check_file_age`.  Arguments passed into the `check_command` field of the service definition follow the command name and are delimited by `!` exclamation points.  Modify the `File age` service definition in `/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/localhost.cfg` to look something like this:

```
define service {
    use             generic-service     ; Name of service template to use
    host_name           localhost
    service_description     File Age
    check_command           check_file_age!3600!5400!200!100!somefile.txt
    notifications_enabled       1
}
```

Ok, now time to verify your configuration files don't have any errors in them:

```
nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

*(...or whatever is the correct path to your nagios.cfg file)*

If there are no errors, restart your nagios service:

```
service nagios restart
```

Comment: Excellent answer. My only quibble is that `register 1` shouldn't be necessary, since [`register` is not inherited](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/objectinheritance.html) and 1 is the default value.

Comment: You're right.  Just found it in the documentation.  Updating my answer. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: `utils.pm` is in the same directory, and I added the export to `profile.d` with no luck.

Comment: <pre>user@host:/usr/local/nagios/libexec$ ll
total 7904
drwxrwxr-x 2 nagios nagios   4096 Sep  9 10:54 ./
drwxr-xr-x 9 root   root     4096 Sep  8 19:43 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nagios nagios 224674 Sep  9 10:53 check_apt*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nagios nagios   2309 Sep  9 10:53 check_breeze*
...
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nagios nagios   3542 Sep  9 10:53 check_file_age*
...
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nagios nagios   1932 Sep  9 10:53 utils.pm*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nagios nagios   2791 Sep  9 10:53 utils.sh*</pre>

Comment: Where does `@INC` come from? Error still there: `(No output on stdout) stderr: Can't locate utils.pm in @INC (you may need to install the utils module) (@INC contains: . /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_file_age line 30. `

Comment: I'll mark this as solved, but the fix I found (sort of) is from http://myfreshthoughts.blogspot.com/2008/09/nagios-check-fails-cant-locate-utilspm.html. I changed `use lib ".";` to `use lib "/usr/local/nagios/libexec";` in `check_file_age`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: This won't fix the underlying issue, but we can work around it with a hack.  Edit `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_file_age`.  Around line 30, change the `use lib` line to look like `use lib "/usr/local/nagios/libexec"`. Save the file. Restart the nagios service.

Comment: Ahh you beat me by 30 seconds ;)

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS 6.9 I could fix the problem by reinstalling the rpm package which provides the file:

`yum reinstall /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/utils.pm`

Answer (score 1):

You can find the first part of the answer here in your logs:

```
(No output on stdout) stderr: Can't locate utils.pm in @INC (you may need to install the utils module) (@INC contains: . /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_file_age line 30.
```

You need to make sure the default user macro `$USER1` is correct, it contains the path to your plugins. Per the Nagios documentation:

#### Defining A User Macro

User macros can be defined in `resource.cfg`, a configuration file that can be found at
`/usr/local/nagios/etc/`. By default, your `resource.cfg` should contain:

```
# Path to the plugins
$USER1$=/usr/local/nagios/libexec
```

On CentOS 7 I had to change the path to `/usr/libexec/nagios` and the same error went away.